# How do you pass multiple parameters of the same type to jQuery Get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to GET some data from a site using jQuery $.get. I need to set 2 parameters of the same type:

```
..&q=Some Text&q=Some other text
```

jQuery appears to be overwriting the first instance of q with the second and only sending 1. Any way around this?

This is the code I was trying to use:

```
var params = {
       "otherParam":"x",
       "q":text,
       "q":title
};
$.get(url, params, mySuccessFunction);
```

Comment: STOP, with the useless meaningless edits. That is a violations of Stackoverflow editorial policy.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try:

```
var params = {
  "otherParam": "x",
  "q": [ text, title ]
};
```

*edit* — more information: array-valued parameters like that are treated specially by jQuery. To appease many common server frameworks, by default (since release 1.5 or 1.6 I think) those will result in parameter names that include "[]" (open- and close-bracket characters) as a suffix (no number, contrary to my erroneous comment below).  If you don't want that, you can set

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

and it'll just be "q" instead of "q[]".

Comment: This doesn't seem to build `&q=text&q=title`. In my test with this solution I get a strange URL : `?otherParam=x&q%5B%5D=text&q%5B%5D=title`

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I'm pretty sure it does work; have you checked to see what's being sent to the server via Firebug or the Chrome debugger or something like that?  Note that jQuery will (I think) create parameters "q[0]", "q[1]" etc, with bracketed indexes in the name.  You can make it not do that by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true`.

Comment: I did check.. it was rejected. jQuery is mangling it. It should be able to handle multiple parameters of same type. But it is not.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo did you try setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional`?  The library is most certainly not broken *unless* you're using a very old version.

Comment: Didn't, but I will just to check.

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qVHuN/) I should have remembered the "traditional" flag when I originally answered; sorry about that.

Comment: Ok Your right! Setting that and your solution also worked. Thx, voted as much as I could up.

Comment: I don't know why any developer would want brackets at the end of the param name for an array, server-side... that's just annoying

Comment: @Amalgovinus it's something that some server-side frameworks like.

Comment: Since jQuery 3.0 this no longer works. You have to define `traditional:true` in the same context where you set the `url`, instead. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (search for `traditional`) and https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ for more details.

Comment: As a historical note, the `traditional` flag was introduced as a workaround for brain-damage in PHP and Ruby on Rails. And instead of calling it `phpcompatibility` or `nonstandard` or `weirdarrays` and requiring explicit opt-in, jquery opted to default for this weirdness and now calls "follow the HTTP spec" as `traditional`.

Answer (score 10):

And another way to solve it that does not require `encodeURIComponent()` or messing with     `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` which I would prefer not to do because I don't want to interfere (even temporarily) with what other parts of the site might be doing simultaneously.

Is:

```
 var params=[ 
       {name:"q", value:title},
       {name:"q", value:text}
 ];
 $.get(url, params, mySuccessFunction);
```

Comment: Note that if you avoid the `$.get()` shorthand and use `$.ajax()` directly, you can force traditional serialization without altering any global settings: `$.ajax({traditional: true, url: ...})`. But this is another good option.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach without modifying `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` is to use `$.param()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

So something like this:

```
var params = {
  "otherParam": "x",
  "q": [ text, title ]
};

$.get(url, $.param(params, true), mySuccessFunction);
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the URL like this :

```
$.get(
   url+'?q='+encodeURIComponent(text)+'&q='+encodeURIComponent(title)+'&otherParam='+encodeURIComponent('x'),
   mySuccessFunction
);
```

Comment: Awesome dude! I was able to use a variant of that to get what I wanted. Kewl!

Comment: How your suggestion below was rejected by my server?

Answer (score -1):

Things are pretty simple and described in jQuery website http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/.

First create a params object

```
var params=[{
    name: 'param1',
    value: 'hello'
},
{
    name: 'param1',
    value: 'alex'
}];
```

next create the data to be sent to the service.

```
var data = jQuery.param(params);
```

That object can be inserted as the data param of the ajax request. I like using a settings object

```
var settings={
    url: 'api/domain/timeline',
    type: 'get',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data
    };
$.ajax(settings);
```