# Alter Ajax Json Query Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

This is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/nHgMX/2/

```
  $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
          dataType: "jsonp",
       data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 7,
        name_startsWith: request.term,
        country: "UK"
      },           
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                value: item.name
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 1,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
```

This link states this: http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html

> featureclass(es) (default= all feature classes); this parameter may
>   occur more than once, example: featureClass=P&featureClass=A

How can I adjust my code to set the feature class to A and P not just P as it is currently?

Comment: Why does this not work `featureClass: "A,P",`?

Comment: `featureClass: ['A', 'P']` and `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`. See [How do you pass multiple parameters of the same type to jQuery Get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876373/how-do-you-pass-multiple-parameters-of-the-same-type-to-jquery-get) for more details.

Comment: @YD1m: Because then the data would be passed as `featureClass=A,B`, which doesn't seem to be supported by the service.

Answer (score 1):

I find 2 solutions:

First one is use method suggested by @George Cummins:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; 

...

$.ajax({
          url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
          dataType: "jsonp",
       data: {
        featureClass: ["A","P"],
```

In second you can add parameters to query string:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?featureClass=A&featureClass=P", // you can concantenate it
```